# Average of properties excluding some

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with, let's say, two properties. One of those properties can have bad values, in the form on a -9999 value.

The aim is to calculate the average of each property, without the bad values.

I am looking to improve my code,  I feel especially wrong about the two loops.

```js
var array = [
{item1: 50, item2: 10},
{item1: 70, item2: -9999},
{item1: 60, item2: 5},
{item1: 40, item2: 7},
]

var avg1 = array.reduce(function(sum, a,i,ar) { sum += a.item1;  return i==ar.length-1?(ar.length==0?0:sum/ar.length):sum},0);

document.getElementById("avg1").innerText = avg1;

var badvalues = 0;

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
if (array[i].item2 == -9999){badvalues++;}
}

var avg2 = array.reduce(function(sum, a,i,ar) {
sum += (a.item2 == -9999? 0: a.item2);
return i==ar.length-1?(ar.length==0?0:sum/(ar.length-badvalues)):sum},0);

document.getElementById("avg2").innerText = avg2;
```

```html
<span id="avg1"></span><br>
<span id="avg2"></span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is already a JavaScript function to aggregate values in an array: [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=example). You can use it like this:

```
const invalidValueForItem2 = -9999;

let result = {
    item1: { sum: 0, count: 0},
    item2: { sum: 0, count: 0},
};

result = array.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    acc.item1.sum += item.Item1;
    ++acc.item1.count;

    if (item.Item2 != invalidValueForItem2) {
        acc.item2.sum += item.Item2;
        ++acc.item2.count;
    }
}, result);
```

Using an object to hold your temporary data we may scale better when you will need more properties and/or if you will average all properties without any knowledge about them. Don't you need to average both `Item1` and `Item2`? Just drop the outer object and keep `{ sum: 0, count: 0}`:

```
let result = { sum: 0, count: 0};

result = array.reduce(function(acc, item) {
    if (item.Item2 != invalidValueForItem2) {
        acc.sum += item.Item2;
        ++acc.count;
    }
}, result);
```

Now you have your result you can calculate the average:

```
const average2 = result.item2.count > 0 ? (result.item2.sum / result.item2.count) : NaN;
```

Do not forget to handle the corner case where there aren't items to sum, in this example when there aren't items the average is `NaN` (but you might want 0), if `Infinity` is appropriate then just make the division.

---

Few more notes about your code:

Indentation is incredibly important. Write just few hundred lines without proper indentation and you won't be able to understand what your code is doing without re-reading everything (and probably introducing bugs here and there).

Unless you have to support older browser you'd better use `let` instead of `var` (and `const` where appropriate).

Let your code *breath*, add space (both horizontally and vertically) and it will be much easier to read. To make code *unreadable* but small is the job of Minifiers/Uglifiers! Compare this with your original call to `reduce()`:

```
var avg1 = array.reduce(function(sum, a, i, ar) {
    sum += a.item1; 
    return i == ar.length - 1 ? (ar.length == 0 ? 0 : sum / ar.length) : sum;
}, 0);
```

Those lines let me introduce few more things:

Do not nest ternary operators unless you're dealing with incredibly simple expressions.

You do not need all the parameters of the `reduce()` function (`ar` is just `array`) then it might be `function(sum, a)`. Also you'd better find a meaningful name for `a` (especially in this case because function documentation *talks* about an *accunulator* then it may be misleading if you do not work often with it). Removing `i` will also stop you to do two things in this function (accumulate the sum and then return the average for the last one).

If your accumulator is a number (initialized to zero) then you do not need to explicitly give it as parameter.

How can you rewrite this? Just few lines when using an arrow function:

```
let sum = array.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.item1);
let average = sum / array.length;
```

However you won't need this code because average for `Item1` is calculated together with `Item2`, use this code for simpler cases.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming from your question that the -9999 values can only appear in item2?

If that's the case then this works:

```js
var array = [
{item1: 50, item2: 10},
{item1: 70, item2: -9999},
{item1: 60, item2: 5},
{item1: 40, item2: 7},
]

sum1 = 0;
avgcount1 = array.length;
sum2 = 0;
avgcount2 = 0;

for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum1 += array[i].item1;
    if (array[i].item2 != -9999) {
        sum2 += array[i].item2;
        avgcount2 += 1;
    }
}

avg1 = sum1 / avgcount1;
avg2 = sum2 / avgcount2;

document.getElementById("avg1").innerText = avg1;
document.getElementById("avg2").innerText = avg2;
```

```html
<span id="avg1"></span><br>
<span id="avg2"></span>
```